No Test or OK button active when setting up a new connection using the Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery
This is the first time we're setting this up and we're stuck at the first stage. I've read through the documentation but I can't get this to work. I'm at the DSN Setup window for a new ODBC connection using the Simba ODBC drive for BigQuery. I've entered the name, description, Service Authentication for the OAuth Mechanism, email and key file path, but when I get down to the Catalog (Project) dropdown, clicking the down arrow does nothing. If I manually type in the Project name it then allows me to select a Dataset from the displayed options but the OK and Test buttons are still greyed out. Any ideas? What am I missing?!
I've tried everything and nothing seems to make those buttons active.

Populate the catalog(project) using the dropdown. If it's not showing the authentication isn't working properly.
